# How do you initialise a CCSprite in Xcode from a class created in SpriteBuilder?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I've created a CCB file as a sprite: MySprite.ccb, with its Custom class set to MySprite.

If I don't want to place it into a layer in SpriteBuilder, but rather initialise objects from it and add them to the scene in Xcode, how do I do that?

**What I've tried:**

Added the following to the end of `application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` in AppDelegate:

```
[CCBReader load:@"MySprite"];
```

And added this to `didLoadFromCCB` in my scnene:

```
MySprite *newSprite = [[MySprite alloc] init];
newSprite.position = CGPointMake(250, 100);
[_physicsNode addChild:newSprite];
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

By the way, everything else is working fine, i.e. everything that's been placed in the scene in SpriteBuilder is working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just load your object with `CCBReader` directly.

And use a cast for `XCode` not to complain.

```
MySprite *newSprite = (MySprite *)[CCBReader load:@"MySprite"];;
newSprite.position = CGPointMake(250, 100);
[_physicsNode addChild:newSprite];
```